# Getting putStrLn to work inside an if-else block

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am writing a palindrome solution in Haskell, and I want the function to show an error if a null is entered. I do not want to use the error function as that halts the program. Hence, I want to show an error message using putStrLn and continue the loop.

I have tried using show to change the input given to the putStrLn but it doesn't work and throws compile time type-error.

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Hey there, What's up! ENTER WORD TO CHECK PALINDROME!"
    word <- getLine
    if null word
        then
            -- putStrLn "This is not a word!"
            main    
    else do
        putStrLn  $ show  $ checkPalindrome word
        main
```

checkPalindrome w = if reverse w == w then True else False

I expect it to show an error, but it only gives an error. What are possible solutions to show a halt-safe error?

Comment: `I expect it to show an error, but it only gives an error.` I have no idea what you mean here. Do you get an error when compiling this, or at run time? Or does it run without error but do something unexpected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write both a `putStrLn "this is not a word!"` and a `main`, you should use a `do` block here:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Hey there, What's up! ENTER WORD TO CHECK PALINDROME!"
    word <- getLine
    if null word
        then do
            putStrLn "This is not a word!"
            main    
    else do
        putStrLn  $ show $ checkPalindrome word
        main
```

That being said, you can simplify the above by making a call at the bottom of the `do` block of the `main`:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Hey there, What's up! ENTER WORD TO CHECK PALINDROME!"
    word <- getLine
    if null word
        then putStrLn "This is not a word!"
        else putStrLn  $ show $ checkPalindrome word
    main
```

or we can, like [@Bergi says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619698/getting-putstrln-to-work-inside-an-if-else-block/56619720#comment99812757_56619720), even put more in the `main` block, like:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Hey there, What's up! ENTER WORD TO CHECK PALINDROME!"
    word <- getLine
    putStrLn $ if null word
        then "This is not a word!"
        else show $ checkPalindrome word
    main
```

If you write this without `do` block, Haskell aims to parse `putStrLn "This is not a word!" main`. This thus means that `putStrLn` is supposed to have type `String -> IO a -> IO a`, but that is not the case.

By using a `do` block, Haskell will [desugar the do block [Haskell'10 report]](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#dx8-47001) into `putStrLn "This is not a word!" >> main`, and this is sound (at least for the type system). Since the bind operator has type [**`(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62-).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! Any insight as to why a separate do-block is needed for this part. An explanation with respect to functional programming would be nice.

Comment: You could even move the `putStrLn` out of the `if` block